# GWT CheckBox doesn't react to onMouseOver/onMouseOut events when styled with 'display: block'

Tags: java, javascript, css, gwt

I'm trying to add `onMouseOver`/`onMouseOut` event handlers to `CheckBox` component in `GWT 2.5.1`  styled with `display: block`:

```
final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("some check box");
cb.addStyleName("check-box");
cb.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(final MouseOverEvent event) {
        log("MouseOver");
    }
});
cb.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(final MouseOutEvent event) {
        log("MouseOut");
    }
});
flowPanel.add(cb);
```

and the related css file contains:

```
.check-box {
    display: block;
}
```

However, `CheckBox` doesn't seem to react to `onMouseOver`/`onMouseOut` events at all. When `display: block` is removed, everything works flawlessly and I see messages in the console while hovering checkbox with mouse. I tried adding `float: left; display: block` but no luck as well. Also, removing `display: block` and adding `float: left` doesn't work as well.

Did anybody encounter something similar or has any clues about what can cause this?

Are there any workarounds for this?

Can this be considered as bug of `GWT`?

P.S. I would like to use `CheckBox` as block-element because it's displayed better this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any other changes in your CSS? Maybe, there is another element in front of the checkbox.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening but you could try wrapping the checkbox in a SimplePanel. It will wrap it in a <div> which is `display: block` by default.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach, no there's any elements overlapping with checkbox for sure. I thought that somehow this may be related to this old GWT bug https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4667 , because it looks very similar.

Comment: @DavidLevesque your workaround worked - I achieved desired look & feel with `onmouseover/onmouseout` events working! You can post it as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening but you could try wrapping the checkbox in a SimplePanel. It will wrap it in a `<div>` which is `display: block` by default.